# Openshift Jboss 7 binary deployment with scaling

Tags: java, git, deployment, jboss, openshift

I have created a simple REST application using the command

- rhc app-create example jbossas-7 --scaling

I used Git initially to push changes to the server without issues.
I am able to access my application, with the following fix for 
503 Service Unavailable with option

- httpchk GET /rest/ping

I changed the deployment type to binary using the command

- rhc app configure -a example --deployment-type binary

with the deployment structure below. I also copied the root.war file from the server and created the binary deployment structure below.

Binary deployment structure

- build_dependencies/ (empty directory)
- dependencies/jbossas/deployments/ROOT.war
- repo/ (empty directory)

I deployed using the command

- rhc app deploy -a example C:\deploy\deploy.tar.gz

The application deployed with no issue ( no errors in Jboss log), however i am not able to access my application externally or internally via port forwarding.

The binary deployment works fine without scaling.

Can someone advise what i have missing in order to deploy precompiled war file with auto scaling?